# c# - I need two runat="server" on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and I found out that I can only have 1 `runat="server"`  on a page at the time. I have 1 in my masterpage and 1 in my login page.

I need both of them to work because i have some asp buttons in my masterpage which I need to edit using the masterpage.master.cs .

I also need it on my login page aswell to check weither the username and password fields equal data out of the database.

If i remove either one of them from a `runat="server"` to a regular form the asp ID's of the buttons and fields are not found in the backend code page. Aswell as the form will be unsubmittable. (ERROR 500)

I am new to .net and C# and was wondering, Is there another way to use the ID's in the backend code file's (*.aspx.cs) or to use multiple `runat="server"` froms (with a workaround or something)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code ... it's really not clear what you are asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way that you can do this, but One `form` will `visible` at a time. It is not possible to `visible` both `form` having `runta="server"`. Just add a `ContentPlaceHolder` in **Master Page** that can use for take `form` in **Child Page**. Then use two `Panel` for take two `form`. After that set visibility false for form of Master Page, and visibility true for form of Child Page. Please check below.

Master Page ASPX:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <form runat="server">
            <h1>Master Page Form</h1>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">

            </asp:ScriptManager>


            <div class="container body-content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <hr />
                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </form>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="login" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Child Page ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="login" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
        <form runat="server" id="loginform">
            <h1>Child Page Form</h1>
        </form>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Child Page CS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel panel1 = (Panel)Master.FindControl("Panel1");
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Web Forms, the form should almost always go in the master page. Most child pages are going to use controls that need to be in a form that runs at the server. Therefore to avoid repeated code, it should be in the master page.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple nested form with runat attribute set to server. Instead of form you can use panel in master page.

Using form runat = "server" in master page result in HTML like

```
<form method="POST">

</form>
```

and when you add content placeholder inside that form tag and you create another form in child page resulting HTML will be

```
<form method="POST"> //master page form
  <form method="POST"> //child page form
  </form>
</form>
```

so at the end you get nested form which is invalid and thus ASP will throw error.

Instead if we replace form tag with panel tag it gives div or any other html tag so resulting HTML will be something like

```
<div>
 <form method="POST">
 </form>
</div>
```

which is valid HTML and thus ASP will not throw any error.

Thus,
in master page

```
<asp:form runat="server".............>    
</asp:form>
```

should be replaced with

```
<asp:panel runate="server"...........>
</asp:panel>
```

If you want form in master page too then you can place form outside of that panel

```
<asp:panel>
 <asp:contentplaceholder id="contentholder" />
</asp:panel>
<asp:form>
</asp:form>
```

Comment: Panel? Can you explain shortly what it does and how I can use it ^^?